Is there a way to align the highchart datalabels and legends to left and right separate for each series in highchart
I want to create a graph similar to below in react apllication. But not getting option
to move text on left an right in highchart.

Parameter avaialble in highchart (align) either left or right.
Customize legend to appear on left and right based on requriement.
Anyone aware how can we achieve below chart in highchart?
[![Chart to be created][1]][1]

const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 125,
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['basket compostion'],
        visible: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        visible: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat:
            '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>' + '{point.percentage:.0f}%</b><br/>',
        shared: true,
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        labelFormatter() {
            const alignment = this.index === this.chart.series.length - 1 ? 'Right Aligned' : 'Left Aligned';
            return `<div>${this.name} (${alignment})<div>`;
        },
        itemStyle: {
            fontSize: '14px',
        },
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            stacking: 'percent',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',
            },
            borderRadius: 5,
        },
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'other products',
            color: '#5041af',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [
                {
                    y: 81.2,
                    custom: { info: 47.29 },
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'focus',
            index: 0,
            color: '#21145f',
            type: 'bar',
            className: 'series-data-label',
            data: [
                {
                    y: 18.2,
                    custom: { info: 10.14 },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};

return (
    <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
    </div>
);


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/9bTeAFKN.png


I was able to achive it by formatting datalabel
const options: Highcharts.Options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 100,
            spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['product Size'],
            visible: false,
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            visible: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            outside: true,
        },
        legend: {
            floating: true,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize: '14px',
            },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                pointWidth: 32,
            },
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'focus',
                index: 1,
                legendIndex: 0,
                showInLegend: false,
                color: '#5041af',
                type: 'bar',
                className: 'series-data-label',
                data: [
                    {
                        y: 18.2,
                        custom: { info: 10.14 },
                    },
                ],
                dataLabels: {
                    padding: 0,
                    align: 'left',
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return `<div style="text-align: center;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:start;font-size:20px;font-wight:500;margin-top: -5px;gap : 11px;font-family: var(--font-face)">
                        <div style="color: #1E1E1E;margin-bottom:3px;line-height:28 px">Focus</div>
                        <div style="font-size:16px;font-wight:500;;line-height:32px;adding-left:15px">10.14</div>
                        <div style="color: var(--disabled-L20);font-size:14px;font-wight:400;line-height:20 px">18.2% of total basket</div>                        
                        </div>`;
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat:
                        '<span style="color:{series.color}">' +
                        '{series.name}</span><br/><b>{point.y}</b> ' +
                        '({point.change}%)<br/>',
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                },
                label: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
            },
            {
                name: 'other products',
                color: '#21145f',
                type: 'bar',
                index: 0,
                legendIndex: 1,
                showInLegend: false,
                data: [
                    {
                        y: 81.2,
                        custom: { info: 47.29 },
                    },
                ],
                dataLabels: {
                    padding: 0,
                    align: 'right',
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return `<div style="text-align: center;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:flex-end;font-size:20px;font-wight:500;margin-top: -5px;gap : 11px;font-family: var(--font-face)">
                        <div style="color: #1E1E1E;margin-bottom:3px;line-height:28 px;">Rest of Basket</div>
                        <div style="font-size:16px;font-wight:500;line-height:32px;padding-right:16px;">10.14</div>
                        <div style="color: var(--disabled-L20);font-size:14px;font-wight:400;line-height:20 px;">18.2% of total basket</div>                        
                        </div>`;
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>81.2</b><br/>',
                },
            },
        ],
    };



As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

There isn’t a direct API option to achieve this, but you can simulate the alignment by translating the legend items.
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function () {
        const chart = this,
          legend = chart.legend,
          items = legend.allItems

        const leftItem = items[0],
          rightItem = items[1]

        const leftItemBBox = leftItem.legendItem.group.element.getBBox(),
          rightItemBBox = rightItem.legendItem.group.element.getBBox()

        leftItem.legendItem.group.attr({
          translateX:
            -chart.plotWidth / 2 + chart.plotLeft + leftItemBBox.width,
        })

        rightItem.legendItem.group.attr({
          translateX:
            chart.plotWidth / 2 - chart.plotLeft + rightItemBBox.width,
        })
      },
    },
  },

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pm5wotu6/
